# problem in deploying app as windows service

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have created an app in C# which does following things

1. Monitors a text file and if something special has been written in file then it takes pictures.
2. Monitors a folder and if any new file is created in that folder then it transfers that file to the server(Server is a wcf service and my app consumes this service as webserivce).
3. Hosts a tcp listener to listen at specific port.

Problem is app works great when i run this app as a console app. However if installed this app as windows service(3 windows services actually for each purpose), system starts showing some slowness and sometimes system hangs. I have used FileSystemWatcher to watch text file and folder. Also tcp listener works in async way and there is no chance any of the task mentioned above can hang the service onstart function.

Answer (score 0):

There probably isn't enough information here for anyone to give you a useful answer.  I would start by adding some logging to see if you can determine where exactly it is stalling.  Then once you have determined that, post the code and see if anyone has any ideas why that would happen there.

Comment: Logging is already added in the app and there is nothing wrong in the code I believe. Infact when i deploy this as console app it works great and system does not show any slowness. However the same code causes problem when deployed as windows service. Target machine is windows xp with 512 mb ram.It is actually an ATM and its mechanical part hangs when i deploy my app as windows service. I just want to know if there is any resource issue with windows service.

Comment: Here *same code* means the windows service same app. Windows services works properly though

Answer (score 0):

Please give a detailed description on "system hangs".

If I were you, I will use WinDbg or another debugger to capture process hang dumps for the new services when they hang, and such dumps should tell what's up.

Answer (score 0):

Shot in the dark:

Usually when I have weird issues running something as a Windows service, but it runs fine as a console app, it is usually one of two reasons:

1. The user the service is running as does not have permissions to perform the action.
2. If it is an OS that has UAC, then that could be the issue.  As a test (not a solution) disable UAC and see if the process works fine.

HTH,
Brian